# Why does this promise resolve when I am not awaiting it

Tags: typescript, promise

I have the following promise, but it seems to resolve without me even awaiting it if I run this code in ts playground.

```
const promises = [later(1000)];


function later(delay:number) {
    return new Promise<void>(function(resolve) {
        setTimeout(() => {
          console.log('test');
          resolve();
        }, delay);
    });
}
```

I only want it to execute when I call

```
await Promise.all(promises);
```

Comment: `await` does not trigger/execute anything. The `Promise` starts with `new Promise(...)`.

Comment: The code is executed the moment `later(1000)` is invoked, which happens at the first line.

Comment: I am assuming `later` is an example here - but note we already provide a promise-returning variant of setTimeout in Node.js you can use "directly" for this.

Comment: A promise is not a function. You cannot "execute" it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As other posts/comments said, `later(1000)` is evaluated right away and don't wait for your `await Promise.all` call to run the promise code.

you could achieve that by doing the following:

```js
const promises = [() => later(1000)];

function later(delay:number) {
    return new Promise<void>(function(resolve) {
        setTimeout(() => {
          console.log('test');
          resolve();
        }, delay);
    });
}

await Promise.all(promises.map(f => f()));
```

Answer (score 3):

Promises are *values* and not actions. Once you have a promise for something *the corresponding action has already happened*.

Luckily the language provides a neat abstraction for actions - functions. The way you typically make a promise "lazy" is by working with a function returning a promise rather than the promise itself.

(Note, this is unlike for example observables which *are* actions and subscribing to them invokes them)

Answer (score 0):

And then there are [*thenables*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve); in Typescript `PromiseLike<T>`.

A naive implementation:

```
function later(delay) {
  return {
    then(onResolve, onReject) {
      return new Promise(resolve => {
        console.log("called new Promise()");
        setTimeout(resolve, delay);
      }).then(onResolve, onReject);
    }
  }
}
```

but for this use case we can completely get rid of the Promise:

```
function later(delay) {
  return {
    then(onResolve) {
      console.log("called setTimeout()");
      setTimeout(onResolve, delay);
    }
  }
}
```

*This implementation assumes that you at most call `later(n).then(...)`, like `await` does. But not `later(n).then(...).then(...)` or `catch()` or `finally()` or all that jazz. If you want all that, use the implementation that returns a `Promise`*

```js
function later(delay) {
  return {
    then(onResolve) {
      console.log("called setTimeout()");
      setTimeout(onResolve, delay);
    }
  }
}

const action = later(1000);

console.log("obj created");

// wait a bit so that its clear that new Promise ain't called immediately
setTimeout(async() => {
  console.log("before awaiting");
  await action;
  console.log("after awaiting");

  await action;
  console.log("awaiting the same object a second time");

  await action;
  console.log("and a third time");

  await later(3000); // also works

  console.log("done");

}, 2000);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{top:0;max-height:100%!important;}
```